# How to insert data from one table to another with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

one

```
    id         thekey        invitedby
    1          sfdsaf           jkfd
    2          fdsalkj           dd
    3           kjk              
    4           ppfdaf           0
    5           fdslkj           op
    6            dsalk           ww
    7           fdsadff          xx
    8            lkjlk           0
    9            klkj            0
```

gx

```
    id      invited      inviter        cost
    1         2             dd           1500
    2         5             op           1200
    3         6             ww           1000
    4         7             xx           1212
```

dkk

```
    id        charge       thekey
```

I try to insert into `dkk`, the rule is somebody who invited others will be insert into table `dkk`, and `gx.id < 4`, at last the data in table `dkk` like following

```
    id        charge       thekey
    1         10            sfdsaf
    2         10            kjk
    3         10            fdslkj
```

The `id` should be inserted in table `one` is `1,3,5`, my sql query is

```
    insert into `dkk` (charge,thekey)
        select 20,thekey
        from one o where exists (select 1 from gx g where g.inviter = o.invitedby)
```

But this insert the id `2,5,6`, the people is invited, not the inviter, any ideas?

Comment: Look at SELECT INTO https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: You have two columns defined in Insert but 3 values.

Comment: @Bleach my typo, i have updated that, please have a look

Comment: table one and gx relation id and invited column right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into dkk (charge,thekey)
select 10, thekey from one o inner join gx g on o.invitedby=g.inviter
where g.id<4
```

Comment: @yepang does it help